# How do I use an SSL Certificate in S3Client using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, tls1.3

I have code to create an S3Client. However, I do not know how to add X509 certificate which is required. The path of the certificate is /opts/containers/certs/az.pem. How do I add the configuration to the code below:

```js
                  export default class S3ClientCreator{

                     async createClient (): Promise<S3Client> {
        
                     const endPoint:EndpointV2 = {url: new URL('https://dns-my-site-s3- 
                                                                        bucket')} 
                     const s3Config = {
                        region: 'us-east-1',
                        endpoint: endPoint,
                        credentials: {
                          accessKeyId: 'ywwn-www' ,
                          secretAccessKey: 'dddpexxdx'
                        }     
                     } 
                       return new S3Client(s3Config);
                    }
                  }
```

I have no idea looking at the documentation and examples an example how to do that. I cannot find any part which describes how to even. I would appreciate if someone how to add the certificate for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the  NodeHttpHandler and requestHandler

```js
          import { NodeHttpHandler } from '@aws-sdk/node-http-handler';
          import { Agent } from 'https';
          import { readFileSync } from 'fs';


          const certs = [readFileSync("/path/to/cert.pem")];
         
          const agent = new Agent({
             rejectUnauthorized: true,
             ca: certs
          });

          const s3Config = {
            region: 'us-east-1',
            endpoint: endPoint,
            credentials: {
               accessKeyId: 'ywwn-www' ,
               secretAccessKey: 'dddpexxdx'
            },
            requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
               httpAgent: agent,
               httpsAgent: agent
            })        
         }
```